# É errado que cada atributo de uma tabela seja uma chave estrangeira em outra tabela apontando para ela?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, orm

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] Estou fazendo um sistema de estoque e na modelagem, ao invés de cada item ter seus atributos definidos eu queria fazer quatro tabelas tags (tag_decimal, tag_data, tag_texto, tag_booleano) que apontavam para a tabela item.
 Como nunca vi isso nas minhas aulas eu queria saber se é fora de padrão, ou tem algum problema.

Comment: Seria melhor mostrar isso pra gente ver melhor todo o contexto. Certo ou errado sempre depende de contexto.

Comment: Poder até pode,  mas já pense como vai ser as consultas, que é quase certeza que vai rolar um full outer join

Comment: Uma quantidade excessiva de outer joins pesam as requisições? Vou colocar o contexto, obrigado pelo aviso

Comment: Acabei de ver a imagem, o jeito que está fazendo pode gerar problemas, pensei que você está querendo fazer uma entidade item e só existia uma única entidade de tags que contemplaria(tag_decimal, tag_data, tag_texto, tag_booleano), assim um item tem 1:1 e uma tag possui 1.1 itens

Comment: Acabei usando só tag de texto mesmo, obrigado pela ajuda pessoal.